# Replacing large numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Imagine I have the following list

```
l = {{1,2,3},{4,10^(16),5}}
```

How do I efficiently replace the large number by a number (zero, for example). I can't seem to do it for a list of lists. Any ideas?

Comment: `l /. _?(# > 1000 &) -> 0` ?

Answer (score 15):

You could use 3-arg [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
Clip[l, {-Infinity, 10^10}, {0, 0}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 5}}

where I used `10^10` as the threshold.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Condition`:

```
l /. x_Integer /; x > 10^6 -> 0
(*{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 5}}*)
```

Or in the same way:

```
l /. x_?NumericQ /; x > 10^6 -> 0
(*{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 0, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 10^(16), 5}}
```

Define a high, low threshold as well as a substitute.

```
thlow = 2;
thhi = 3;
subst = 11;
```

Find positions of the entries that fall within the limits `[2,3]`:

```
pos = Position[l, x_ /; thlow <= x <= thhi, Infinity, Heads -> False]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

To delete:

```
Delete[l, pos]
```

To replace with the substitute:

```
ReplacePart[l, Thread[pos -> subst]]
```

> {{1, 11, 11}, {4, 10000000000000000, 5}}

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want something generalizable. Let's say your threshold is 10^10, then something like this:

```
Map[If[# > 10^10, 0, #] &, l, {2}]
```

You could also use ReplaceAll:

```
ReplaceAll[l, _?(GreaterThan[10^10]) -> 0]
```